# In the ios Contacts framework how can you determine the number to text?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, contacts-framework

There are many different phone number fields for contacts (
iphone, main, mobile, home, work etc) which is the best one/ what is the best algorithm for determining the mostly likely candidate to be the contact's personal mobile phone? Can I access texting history for said contact? I was thinking just find the field that is populated in an ordered list such as mobile, then main if not mobile, then iphone if not main etc.

Any thoughts/best practices?

Answer (score 1):

1. "Can I access texting history for said contact?" -> No (privacy)
2. It sounds like you have a good approach to going through numbers - no way to know for certain, but searching through them as you state should be a great start.